# Execute chrome extension on website after loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to stackoverflow and even new to programming. I just started to learn to progam online and I am trying to make my first google extension.
(but because I am a complete newbie the code might also look terrible - and not efficient)

I want to make a google extension that hides/shows certain threads on a forum (related to facebook, instagram, twitter, ...) based on the values of check boxes in the popup.html of the google extension.

I have most of the code working. 
If you click the google extension a pop up is shown and check boxes can be set. After hitting the 'instellingen bewaren' button these settings are saved to chrome.storage and implemented. 
Also when you are on the forum and click the chrome extension the filtering of the threads is done based on your last settings.

The problem I have is that I want the filtering to be done alread when the forum page is loaded. I now always have to click the chrome extension icon to start the filtering. If I go to another page on the forum I need to click the extension again to start filtering again.

I have a feeling that all the things I am trying are resulting in the code to be executed after loading the popup.html instead of loading the forum page (at least that is what I conclude when I look at the console of both pages and perform some console.log commands).

Things I tried:

- making a background.js file and using the command (also updated the manifest.json file): chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
- placing this in my content.js file: 
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", filter);
  or
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
  or
  window.

This is the current code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "  Schifters tool",
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "storage" ],
  "version": "0.1",
      "icons": {
      "128": "images/S-128.png",
      "16": "images/S-16.png",
      "48": "images/S-48.png"
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/schifters.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },   
   "description": "  Schifters Tool",
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://schifters.be/viewforum.php*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Schifters Tool</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

<body>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="https://schifters.be/index.php" target="_blank">Schifters Tool</a>
      <span href="https://schifters.be/index.php" class="version">(1.0.0)</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
   <form> 
   <div class="activeerFilters">
   <p>Geef aan welke posts verborgen moeten worden:</p>
  </div>
  </form>

   <form>   
   <div class="filters">
    <label for="facebook"><input id="facebook" type="checkbox" name="filtering"> Facebook wedstrijd</label>
 </div>
  </form>

  <button id="save">Instellingen bewaren</button>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <script src="content.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

content.js

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var facebook = document.getElementById('facebook').checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    facebookStatus: facebook,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Instellingen zijn bewaard';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);    
    filterAlles();
  }); 
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    facebookStatus: false,  
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('facebook').checked = items.facebookStatus;
    // filtering of the threads
    filterAlles();
    });
}

function filterAlles() {
    filterFacebook();
}

function filterFacebook() {
    if(document.getElementById('facebook').checked) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "verbergFacebook.js"});
    } else {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "toonFacebook.js"});
    }
  }  


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

toonFacebook.js

```
{
// place all posts in an Array
 const topics = Array.from(document.querySelector('[class="forumbg"]').querySelectorAll('ul>li'));

// show facebook posts
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; ++i) {
//    console.log(topics[i].textContent);
    if (topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null ){
        console.log('ok')
            topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]').parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "";
} else {
//      console.log('nok')
    }
  }

}
```

verbergFacebook.js

```
{
// place all posts in an array
 const topics = Array.from(document.querySelector('[class="forumbg"]').querySelectorAll('ul>li'));

// hide all facebook posts
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; ++i) {
//    console.log(topics[i].textContent);
    if (topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null ){
        console.log('ok')
            topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]').parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
} else {
//      console.log('nok')
    }
  }

}
```

and like the last 2 js. files there a a lot of extra files. Each time one for hiding a certain type of threads and one for showing a certain type of threads.

Maybe it is not efficient to have this code in ~20 different files? But I couldn't get my checkbox values working in these .js files.?

I expect the chrome extension to filter the threads on the forum (based on the settings of the check boxes from last time) immediately after loading the forum page.

The filter option already works when the extension popup is shown or when you change checkbox settings and click the button on the popup.html page.
But this last function is a mystery for me :)

Thnx in advance!

Comment: That's a lot for a complete newbie. Try to narrow down the problem. This -- `at content.js:286` -- isn't going to help.

Comment: Tnx, i removed that section from my question.

Comment: 1) The content.js file you posted is 227 lines, so the error at line 286 looks like it doesn't match the code. 2) Re: narrowing down the problem take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 3) The content script [runs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) after DOMContentLoaded by default, so try calling the function to do the initial filtering (you say it's `filter`, but no such function is defined in the code you've posted) from top-level. This `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);` will never fire.

Comment: 4) If running on DOMContentLoaded doesn't see some elements on the page (check with console.log), they may be added dynamically by the page's JS. Try `setTimeout()` to test that hypothesis.

Comment: @Nicolay: 1) you are right. The error refers to ```document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options); ```` (but the save button seems to work)

Comment: @Nicolay 2) I cleaned up the code as suggested. It should be more 'readable' now.

Comment: @Nicolay 3) the ```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);``` is used to enter my last values of the checkboxes in the popup.html file (when the chrome extension script is clicked and this page is loaded). I tried to add ```filterAlles();``` to the content.js file but it had no effect.

Comment: @Nicolay 4) sorry, I don't know what you mean with it or what I need to test. (newbie level here... :( )

Comment: When I add this code in the content.js script then the code is run on pageload ```const topics = Array.from(document.querySelector('[class="forumbg"]').querySelectorAll('ul>li'));
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; ++i) {
 if (topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null ){
  console.log('ok');
  topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]').parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
} else {
 }
  }```

Comment: This code was present in seperate .js files to hide/show data in the forum. in my content.js script I activate it from the popup.html page with ``` chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "toonFacebook.js"});``` But this doesn't work onload for my main page... I think... I'll look into it further this evening.  But i have a good feeling the solution is near :)

Answer (score 0):

I' have it working. (more ore less)
The setup is as follows:

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "  Schifters tool",
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "storage" ],
  "version": "0.1.1",
      "icons": {
      "128": "images/Schifters.png",
      "16": "images/Schifters-16x16.png",
      "32": "images/schifters-32x32.png"
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/schifters.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }, 
   "description": "  Schifters Tool",
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://schifters.be/viewforum.php*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js", "popup.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Schifters Tool</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="https://schifters.be/index.php" target="_blank"><img class="logo-icon" src="images/Schifters.png"></a> <a href="https://schifters.be/index.php" target="_blank">Schifters Tool</a>
      <span href="https://schifters.be/index.php" class="version">(0.1.1)</span>
    </h1>
  </div>

   <form> 
   <div class="activeerFilters">
   <p>Geef aan welke posts verborgen moeten worden:</p>
   <p><label for="activeerFilters"><input id="activeerFilters" type="checkbox" name="activeerFiltering">Activeer de filter opties</label></p>
  </div>
  </form>

   <form> 

   <div class="filters">


    <label for="gespeeld"><input id="gespeeld" type="checkbox" name="filtering"> <a href="#"><img src="./images/GESPEELD.png" alt="GESPEELD"></a> GESPEELD</label>
    <label for="facebook"><input id="facebook" type="checkbox" name="filtering"> <a href="#"><img src="./images/facebookWedstrijd.png" alt="Facebook wedstrijd"></a> Facebook wedstrijd</label>
  </div>
  </form>


  <button id="save">Instellingen bewaren</button>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <script src="content.js"></script> 
  <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

content.js

```
var topics = Array.from(document.querySelector('[class="forumbg"]').querySelectorAll('ul>li')); 

function filterAlles(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    activeerFiltersStatus:  false,
    gespeeldStatus: false,
    facebookStatus: false
      }, function(items) {
    console.log("we zitten in de loop van de nieuwe functie");
    for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; ++i) 
    { 
        if ( items.activeerFiltersStatus &&
           ((topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null && items.facebookStatus) ||
            (topics[i].querySelector('[title="Markering verwijderen"]') !== null && items.gespeeldStatus))      
        )
        { 
            console.log('ok - we gaan filteren'); 
            if (topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null){
            topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]').parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";           
            }
            if (topics[i].querySelector('[title="Markering verwijderen"]') !== null){
            topics[i].querySelector('[title="Markering verwijderen"]').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";          
            }           
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]') !== null){
            topics[i].querySelector('[style="background-image: url(./images/icons/misc/facebook.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"]').parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "";           
            }
            if (topics[i].querySelector('[title="Markering verwijderen"]') !== null){
            topics[i].querySelector('[title="Markering verwijderen"]').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "";          
            }       
        } 
      }} );
}  

filterAlles();
```

(this is now correctly run when my forum page is loaded)

and only one other .js file this time

popup.js

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var activeerFilters = document.getElementById('activeerFilters').checked;
  var gespeeld = document.getElementById('gespeeld').checked;
  var facebook = document.getElementById('facebook').checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    activeerFiltersStatus: activeerFilters,
    gespeeldStatus: gespeeld,
    facebookStatus: facebook
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Instellingen zijn bewaard';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);

//  filterAlles();
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"})
  }); 
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    activeerFiltersStatus:  false,
    gespeeldStatus: false,
    facebookStatus: false   
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('activeerFilters').checked = items.activeerFiltersStatus;
    document.getElementById('gespeeld').checked = items.gespeeldStatus;
    document.getElementById('facebook').checked = items.facebookStatus;

    if(document.getElementById('activeerFilters').checked) {
    document.getElementById("gespeeld").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('facebook').disabled = false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("gespeeld").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('facebook').disabled = true;
    }
    });
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);


var checkbox = document.getElementById("activeerFilters");

// Dit zorgt ervoor dat de checkboxen sensitief worden als je de 'activeer filters optie' selecteert
checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
    document.getElementById("gespeeld").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('facebook').disabled = false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("gespeeld").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('facebook').disabled = true;
    }
});
```

In this setup the threads are hidden when the page is loaded (based on the last settings of the check boxes in the popup.html file).
When settings are changed in the popup.html file then these changes are also applied.
So is seems to be working.

However I get some errors in console (and I don't know if this is an issue or not).
When I go to the console of the popup.html file I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at popup.js:48
it's referring to this line of code:

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

And that seems logical as the 'forum webpage' doesn't have the save button (that button is in the popup.html file).
Do I need to change anything in my code to avoid this? Or can I just ignore it?

The other error is in the popup.html console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at content.js:1
it's referring to this line of code:

```
var topics = Array.from(document.querySelector('[class="forumbg"]').querySelectorAll('ul>li'));
```

I think this is because the 'document.' should be changed to 'chrome.tabs.' when run from the popup.html page. But I find it strange that the forum threads are hidden correctly. How is it possible that this is working from the popup.html file if we can't placed the forum threads in an array.